# Python curiosity: [] > lambda n: n

Tags: python, list, lambda, comparison-operators

One of my coworkers was using the builtin [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function (on Python 2.7), and he found a weird behavior.

By mistake, instead of using the keyword argument *key* (as in `key=lambda n: n`) to pre-sort the list passed as a parameter, he did:

```
 >>> max([1,2,3,3], lambda n : n)
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

He was doing what in the documentation is explained as:

*If two or more positional arguments are provided, the largest of the positional arguments is returned.*, so now I'm curious about why this happens:

```
>>> (lambda n:n) < []
True
>>> def hello():
...     pass
... 
>>> hello < []
True
>>> len(hello)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

I know it's not a big deal, but I'd appreciate if any of the *stackoverflowers* could explain how those comparisons are internally made (or point me into a direction where I can find that information). **:-)**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you go from `lambda n: n` to deciding to compare against function objects? :)

Comment: @Jon Clements: well... just making tests... since lambda is a function, I started making weird tests with functions **:D** (oh, and I did waaaay more than the ones I published here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2 orders objects of different types rather arbitrarily. It did this to make lists *always* sortable, whatever the contents. Which direction that comparison comes out as is really not of importance, just that one always wins. As it happens, the [C implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0012d4f0ca59/Objects/object.c#l784) falls back to comparing type names; `lambda`'s type name is `function`, which sorts before `list`.

In Python 3, your code would raise an exception instead:

```
>>> (lambda n: n) < []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: function() < list()
```

because, as you found out, supporting arbitrary comparisons mostly leads to hard-to-crack bugs.

Comment: Yeah, we tried on Python 3 and we saw the exception... Just wondering why Python 2.7 had this behavior :)

Answer (score 6):

Everything in Python (2) can be compared, but some are fairly nonsensical, as you've seen.

```
>>> (lambda n:n) < []
True
```

Python 3 resolves this, and produces exceptions instead.